# how to Add image to Database as it accepts null value meaning the Image Column, optional image to add for user

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a win form that let user enter 2 textboxes that are obligatory after selecting a combobox, and a button to add image if he wants and another button where the insert to sql happens
My upload image code:

```
private void BUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CmbImo.SelectedIndex != -1) { 
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                   pictureBox1.Text = open.FileName;
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
            }
                else

                {
                    label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    label2.Text = "please Upload an Image";
                }



            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Do Select an Imo Vessel !!");
            }

        }
```

and this is the procedure that i have in the last add button that inserts into sql

```
public void SaveATLast()
        {
            string image = pictureBox1.Text;
            if (CmbImo.SelectedIndex != -1 && textBox1.Text!="" && textBox3.Text != "") { 
            cnx.Open();
           // string image = pictureBox1.Text;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Bay2(VessImo,CatwalkHeight,BayName,ImageBay) values (@VessImo,@CatwalkHeight,@BayName,@imgdata)", cnx);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VessImo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CmbImo.SelectedItem.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatwalkHeight", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BayName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bimage;
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BayName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnx.Close();
                //this.Close();
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            }else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please Do Fill all Textboxes !!");
            }
        }
```

when getting to the point where i dont wanna add a picture but instead just filling the two txtboxes needed it give me

> System.ArgumentException: 'The path does not have a conforming form.'

UPDATE: 
Just to be clear when i actually click upload image and fill the 2 textboxes it actually does get inserted in database , what i want is it doesnt matter if picture is uploaded or not meaning if picturebox is empty or not 
Note that in sql the image column is NOT SET TO  "NOT NULL"

Comment: What is the error your are facing?

Comment: sorry i edited the post its like the path does not have... it is translated from frensh

Comment: If you don't want to add the image you can use different sql statement that excludes it or assign `DBNull.Value` to the parameter. As an aside, you should prefer `varbinary` over `image` sql data type.

Comment: thanks for the tip about VArbinary , but i dont think not excluding image or setting it up to null is convenient thats just to how i write the code , if you could explain more would be helpfull

Comment: I can't hear you unless you @ tag me. Please explain what you would like to happen if the picture box is not set. You have that column in the table, if you add a row that value has to either be null or it has to not be null. Are you looking to load a "default" image, like a placeholder?

Comment: @Crowcoder no the picturebox is just a place to show user the picture he uploaded in other hands theres another button "ADD" that actually add the values of everything in that form and i want that if the user doesnt want to select a picturebox ,its fine, i really hope i answered , and thanks for ur responses

Comment: In that case refer to my first comment. I don't know how to explain any better. Regardless, your actual error is about trying to read file that is not there so you need to do some validation before you try to create a bitmap from a bad path.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property to get the image path. The correct property is `ImageLocation`.

```
 string image = pictureBox1.ImageLocation;
```

If your image field in database is null then you need to set the value to `DBNull`.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = (bimage == null) ? DBNull.Value : bimage;
```

Comment: thanks sir , i changed it and another error meesage showed up saying that the value can not be null , parameter name 'path'

Comment: Do you have any image set in the Picture Box? Also can you post the detailed error and update your question.

Comment: no by default its empty , and once user click on Upload and acually select an image it goes into the picturebox and then he clicks add and get added to database

Comment: What is the value of `pictureBox1.ImageLocation;`? I'm sure it's not set that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: ok im confused what do you mean by value of image location , its an input from user so basically its value is not know please correct me if anything wrong i really havent slept in 17hours.

Comment: See my updated answer. Take care of your self buddy!

Comment: @vendettamit it is unusual, but OP is setting the `Text` property to the image file name so it *should* work. However your code to `AddWithValue` is wrong, you are setting the value to litterally `SqlDbType.Image` then immediately overwriting it with the image or null. It might work but it's a round-a-bout way to get a parameter set and it does not appropriately set the sql type.

Comment: @Crowcoder Indeed, I didn't realize he is actually setting the Text property to image path. I used same code that OP posted for inserting into the image column. If column allows null then it should accept the value `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: I understand, but, no offense, it is bad code. Since it works OP might think that is the "right" way and use it forever. That overload of `AddWithValue` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: How is it a bad code? The method you are thinking of is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). This is the new method that's available on `SqlParameterCollection` and returns a `SqlParameter` object, and you can set it's Value property to any valid values.

Comment: Think about it. You are using AddWith**Value** and then also using the `Value` property. What method do you think I'm thinking of? You are the one using `AddWithValue`, I"m the one saying don't use it.